# Unable to reproduce: HttpRequest properties not thread safe (.Net 7)

Tags: .net-core

Background: In a production webservice we are getting nullrefs on Framework (.Net 7) calls to HttpRequest properties (e.g. Query, Form).

I understand asynchronous access to properties that use HttpRequest Features is likely to cause this (we suspect Application Insights), but I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on a dev machine.

I have actually tried as hard as I can to "break" DefaultHttpRequest with concurrent read and write access but no luck! Perhaps someone can suggest changes to the code below?

`
// request is the current actual request of type DefaultHttpRequest

```
         List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> tasks = Enumerable
            .Range(0, 55)
            .Select(__ => Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                {
                    _ = request.Query;
                    _ = request.Headers;
                    _ = request.Cookies;
                    request.QueryString = new QueryString("?asdf");
                    request.Cookies.Append("x", "y");
                    request.Cookies.RemoveAll((kvp) => true);
                }
            })).ToList();
        Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();`
```

Tried: Concurrent access to supposedly non-thread-safe properties of DefaultHttpRequest
Expected: Null reference or other exception